# Bind DataTable to Excel spreadsheet directly in C#

Tags: c#, excel, data-binding, datatable

I am building a C# VSTO Add-in, and looking for ways to bind System.Data.DataTable directly to Excel spreadsheet (like binding a datasource) and track user modified cells in the spreadsheet and read the changes back in C#.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at using ListObjects.  You can directly bind an in-memory datatable to a ListObject.  You don't have to display all the fields when you add this listobject (table) to a worksheet.

For example:

```
Public WithEvents decideList As Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.ListObject
Public dt As System.Data.DataTable = New System.Data.DataTable("MasterData")
' Load data into the datatable dt

Dim worksheet As Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Worksheet = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(sheet) 'where sheet is the native worksheet where you are locating the ListObject
Dim cell As Excel.Range = worksheet.Range("$A$1:$D$4")

decideList = worksheet.Controls.AddListObject(cell, "decideList")
decideList.AutoSetDataBoundColumnHeaders = True
decideList.SetDataBinding(dt, Nothing, { "FirstName", "LastName", "Company" })
```

The only problem is persistence.  You will need to save out the the full datatable prior closing the spreadsheet (unless you display the entire datatable in the ListObject).

When you re-open the worksheet, you'll need a method to load the table into an in-memory datatable, the re-bind it.

I hope that helps!

There are a few links online. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668212.aspx

The only issues I have had is sometimes its better to update the underlying datatable rather than use the Excel worksheet.  To do this, you can set up events that fire on any changes to the ListObject.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct method to bind `DataTable` to Excel spreadsheet.

You have to enumerate rows and columns in your `DataTable` and insert data into Worksheet.

Then you have to decide when to update back (i.e. during saving Workbook - then create event handler for `BeforeSave` event) and enumerate rows and columns in Worksheet moving values back into `DataTable` and update database.

Comment: ,Thanks for the response.  
I have more than 10,000 rows that I retrieve from Database via API and bind to excel enumerating the rows/cols in DataTable.  Out of which, the user could update only 500 rows and publish, in which case I need to find the modified/dirty rows determined by keeping track of the original and modified values.
Is there an efficient way to handle this using C# Excel VSTO.

Comment: 3 ideas - a) store original DataTable and then compare what you wrote into Excel with what is in Excel with values inside DataTable - then you can update really modified rows b) If you cannot store DataTable in memory (program is closed and opened) you can also serialize DataSet into binary file next to Excel file c) You can write data to Worksheet then copy it and protect that you have original values an 2nd Sheet - then by comparing them you can find changed rows

Comment: These are interesting ideas, Thanks for sharing.